# How can I make my custom board use the programmer selected in "Tools->Programmer" when the Upload button is pushed?

Tags: uploading

I've created a custom board that can be programmed using any one of several programmers defined in `programmers.txt`. I would like the user to be able to choose which programmer to use via the "Tools->Programmer" menu options.

I tried using `{protocol}` and `{upload.protocol}` in `platform.txt` to pass the programmer to the upload tool, but neither seem to be defined when the `Upload` button is used to initiate the upload (they are defined if `Upload using programmer` is selected from the menu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you do not have a `protocol` listed in the `boards.txt` file. If the uploader sees protocol is `null` then it will fall back to using the same code that "Upload using programmer" does.

Relevant code in `SerialUploader.java`:

```
    if (usingProgrammer || prefs.get("upload.protocol") == null) {
      return uploadUsingProgrammer(buildPath, className);
    }
```